# How to use the base58 in c++

Tags: address, c++, p2pkh, base58, base58check

its been a while after i done with my python bitcoin miner

And i realize that python is slower to do mining stuff, so i decided to rebuild it in c++ as you guys know c++ the faster than other programming language

But i have a problem to use base58 decode to hexadecimal in c++

**Python code**

```
import base58

BtcAddr: str = "1Htcz9y5sVuztuwTnfpWR4dhqirhLMcK7r"

base58.b58decode_check(BtcAddr).hex()
```

And the output will be this

> 00b9454405a39efcb023127cd6daacf9c133b84df3

But i need that in c++ code, i already search online but i didnt find anything helpful

Can you guys help me? I really need the source code in c++

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### This solution is used by Bitcoin Core

#### base58.h

```
// Copyright (c) 2009-2010 Satoshi Nakamoto
// Copyright (c) 2009-2015 The Bitcoin Core developers
// Copyright (c) 2023 Loopite.

#ifndef CRYPTO_BASE58_H
#define CRYPTO_BASE58_H

#include <string>
#include <vector>

/**
 * Encode a byte sequence as a base58-encoded string.
 * pbegin and pend cannot be NULL, unless both are.
 */
std::string encodeBase58(const unsigned char* pbegin, const unsigned char* pend);

/**
 * Encode a byte vector as a base58-encoded string
 */
std::string encodeBase58(const std::vector<unsigned char>& vch);

/**
 * Decode a base58-encoded string (psz) into a byte vector (vchRet).
 * return true if decoding is successful.
 * psz cannot be NULL.
 */
bool decodeBase58(const char* psz, std::vector<unsigned char>& vchRet);

/**
 * Decode a base58-encoded string (str) into a byte vector (vchRet).
 * return true if decoding is successful.
 */
bool decodeBase58(const std::string& str, std::vector<unsigned char>& vchRet);

#endif // CRYPTO_BASE58_H
```

#### base58.cpp

```
// Copyright (c) 2009-2010 Satoshi Nakamoto
// Copyright (c) 2009-2015 The Bitcoin Core developers
// Copyright (c) 2023 Loopite

#include "base58.h"

#include <iterator>
#include <cstring>

#include <cassert>

/** All alphanumeric characters except for "0", "I", "O", and "l" */
static const char* pszBase58 { "123456789ABCDEFGHJKLMNPQRSTUVWXYZabcdefghijkmnopqrstuvwxyz" };

std::string encodeBase58(const unsigned char* pbegin, const unsigned char* pend)
{
    // Skip & count leading zeroes.
    int zeroes = 0;
    int length = 0;
    while (pbegin != pend && *pbegin == 0) {
        pbegin++;
        zeroes++;
    }
    // Allocate enough space in big-endian base58 representation.
    int size = (pend - pbegin) * 138 / 100 + 1; // log(256) / log(58), rounded up.
    std::vector<unsigned char> b58(size);
    // Process the bytes.
    while (pbegin != pend) {
        int carry = *pbegin;
        int i = 0;
        // Apply "b58 = b58 * 256 + ch".
        for (auto it = b58.rbegin(); (carry != 0 || i < length) && (it != b58.rend()); it++, i++) {
            carry += 256 * (*it);
            *it = carry % 58;
            carry /= 58;
        }

        assert(carry == 0);
        length = i;
        pbegin++;
    }
    // Skip leading zeroes in base58 result.
    auto it = b58.begin() + (size - length);
    while (it != b58.end() && *it == 0)
        it++;
    // Translate the result into a string.
    std::string str;
    str.reserve(zeroes + (b58.end() - it));
    str.assign(zeroes, '1');
    while (it != b58.end())
        str += pszBase58[*(it++)];
    return str;
}

std::string encodeBase58(const std::vector<unsigned char>& vch)
{
    return encodeBase58(&vch[0], &vch[0] + vch.size());
}

bool decodeBase58(const char* psz, std::vector<unsigned char>& vch)
{
    // Skip leading spaces.
    while (*psz && isspace(*psz))
        psz++;
    // Skip and count leading '1's.
    int zeroes = 0;
    int length = 0;
    while (*psz == '1') {
        zeroes++;
        psz++;
    }
    // Allocate enough space in big-endian base256 representation.
    int size = strlen(psz) * 733 /1000 + 1; // log(58) / log(256), rounded up.
    std::vector<unsigned char> b256(size);
    // Process the characters.
    while (*psz && !isspace(*psz)) {
        // Decode base58 character
        const char* ch = strchr(pszBase58, *psz);
        if (ch == nullptr)
            return false;
        // Apply "b256 = b256 * 58 + ch".
        int carry = ch - pszBase58;
        int i = 0;
        for (auto it = b256.rbegin(); (carry != 0 || i < length) && (it != b256.rend()); ++it, ++i) {
            carry += 58 * (*it);
            *it = carry % 256;
            carry /= 256;
        }
        assert(carry == 0);
        length = i;
        psz++;
    }
    // Skip trailing spaces.
    while (isspace(*psz))
        psz++;
    if (*psz != 0)
        return false;
    // Skip leading zeroes in b256.
    auto it = b256.begin() + (size - length);
    while (it != b256.end() && *it == 0)
        it++;
    // Copy result into output vector.
    vch.reserve(zeroes + (b256.end() - it));
    vch.assign(zeroes, 0x00);
    while (it != b256.end())
        vch.push_back(*(it++));
    return true;
}

bool decodeBase58(const std::string& str, std::vector<unsigned char>& vchRet)
{
    return decodeBase58(str.c_str(), vchRet);
}
```

#### Tests

```
[ RUN      ] App.base58_Basics
00b9454405a39efcb023127cd6daacf9c133b84df30ce3172d
[       OK ] App.base58_Basics (0 ms)
```

From C++ code:

```
/**
 * @Author: Loopite
 * @Description: Test for base58 encodings
 */

#include <gtest/gtest.h>

#include "crypto/base58.h"

#include <set>

TEST(App, base58_Basics)
{
    /*
     * Decode
     */
    const std::string data
    {
        "1Htcz9y5sVuztuwTnfpWR4dhqirhLMcK7r" // P2PKH address
    };

    std::vector<unsigned char> decodedContent;
    decodeBase58(data, decodedContent);

    // ...Print content of decoded data...
    for (unsigned char i : decodedContent)
        std::cout << std::hex << std::setfill('0') << std::setw(2) << static_cast<unsigned int>(i);

    std::cout << std::endl;
}
```

### NOTE

The output is `00b9454405a39efcb023127cd6daacf9c133b84df30ce3172d` NOT `00b9454405a39efcb023127cd6daacf9c133b84df3` for the string `1Htcz9y5sVuztuwTnfpWR4dhqirhLMcK7r`. See https://appdevtools.com/base58-encoder-decoder.

Comment: I see but that includes with hexadecimal value + checksum right? Well i dont want the checksum value, i only want the hexadecimal value

Comment: The thing is P2PKH has this structure: networkFlag (1 byte) + address (20 bytes since it has been hashed by RIPEMD-160) + checksum (4 bytes). Therefore the checksum is required. However if you WANT the hexadecimal value WITHOUT checksum you can process like this:
``1Htcz9y5sVuztuwTnfpWR4dhqirhLMcK7r`` <=>
``00b9454405a39efcb023127cd6daacf9c133b84df30ce3172d`` (With checksum) <=>
``00b9454405a39efcb023127cd6daacf9c133b84df3`` (Without checksum) <=>
``13ahvXA4uoeMuX4iKJW1mQkYjCWbt`` (Encoded in base58)
You just have to parse output to get networkFlag and address separatly by using substr.

Comment: /!\. You should know that the checksum is REQUIRED. So you'll have to keep it from LEGACY addresses. It's part of the protocol. Functions you see above allow you to encode/decode base58 sequence. That's it.

Comment: So what youre trying to say is that i need to include the checksum in order to make a raw transactions?

Comment: In a raw transaction this is different. You'll have just to provide the address. This field can be determined from the Base58Check (1Htcz9y5sVuztuwTnfpWR4dhqirhLMcK7r).
_To sum up:_ Base58**Check** requires a **checksum**. But raw txs need address only.

Comment: yeah i see, thanks for your help:)

Comment: hello sir, sorry to bother you but i face some issue with your code, the result from decodeBase58() only can be print through for loop, now heres the problem. How can i store the result inside a viarable?

Comment: decodeBase58 returns nothing. However, it takes a vector of unsigned char in **reference** : ``decodeBase58(..., std::vector<unsigned char>& vchRet);``. For example, in my 'Tests' section, I store the result in my ``decodedContent`` variable. Then you can read data inside. But this is a **variable of bytes**. You can do whatever you want with it. Besides, I used here a for each loop in order to print the result of decoding operation (It was a debug option to give you the decoded result).

Comment: Ahh i see, you i cant store them in viarable?

Comment: Of course you can. It was done in my example as ``decodedContent`` variable. But that's a matter for the code. I recommend that you ask any other questions about this on the stackoverflow C++ forum unless you have other questions about **Bitcoin**.